# UDP Server that sends data back to client C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, client

I'm using the following code to test a simple UDP server which has to receive a message from the client and then send it back.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 

#define PORT     8080 
#define MAXLINE 1024 

// Driver code 
int main() { 
    int sockfd; 
    char buffer[MAXLINE]; 
    char *hello = "Hello from server"; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr; 

    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) { 
        perror("socket creation failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr)); 
    memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr)); 

    // Filling server information 
    servaddr.sin_family    = AF_INET; // IPv4 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    // Bind the socket with the server address 
    if ( bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,  
            sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 ) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    int len, n; 

    len = sizeof(cliaddr);  //len is value/resuslt 

    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE,  
                MSG_WAITALL, ( struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, 
                &len); 
    buffer[n] = '\0'; 
    printf("Client : %s\n", buffer); 
    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello),  
        MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, 
            len); 
    printf("Hello message sent.\n");  

    return 0; 
}
```

The problem is that it receive the message, but I don't know how to make it go back to the client!
I'm using netcat for testing.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: So what is the problem exactly with your program? Obviously you have already attempted to receive and send. What results did you get?

Comment: @kaylum the message appears on the server side, but it doesn't go back to the client side

Comment: For starters, check the return value of all function calls, `sendto` in particular here. If that fails, you have a lead. If it doesn't,
 think about what else you can do to debug. For example, use wireshark/tcpdump to see what was actually sent.

Comment: @kaylum The `sendto` function returns a 4.

Comment: How did you test it? It worked for me. Add the exact run log to your question.

Comment: @kaylum I just declared an `int` which gave me the result of `sendto`... I just need to know how to send back the message received from the server to the client and print it on server side

Comment: But that's what we are trying to debug. You already have a `sendto` which looks roughly correct. So we need more details on exactly how you ran your nc command, what input you put in, what result you got etc.

Comment: `sendto()` shouldn't ever return 4 in that code...

Comment: @kaylum yeah, I'm using `netcat -u 127.0.0.1 8080` and it just show the `Hello from server` once, while it should show it twice (one time for sending, one time for receiving), or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. netcat will only print what the server sends once. What did you type into netcat? For example, if you enter "abc" into netcat the server should say "Client : abc" and netcat should show "Hello from server"

Comment: @kaylum yeah, and it's right! I need both of them to be printed on the client side, is it possible? Like, if I insert by input the message to send on the client side, it has to appear back always on the client side

Comment: Yes of course it is possible. Send `buffer` instead of (or in addition to) `hello`.

Comment: @kaylum, ok, but now it doesn't appear anything

Comment: Works for me `sendto(sockfd, (const char *)buffer, strlen(buffer)`. Maybe you made the wrong change. Please be explicit - show the code you changed.

Comment: @kaylum yeah yeah it's right! I just didn't put anything on the command line, so it turned back a blank space. Thank you very very much!